# How to set up a layered navigation filter with swatches - but not use as a configurable product option

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, color-swatches

I would like to use an attribute set (with swatches) to feed into a filter on the layered navigation on category pages.

However I do not want this attribute set to be an option on the product detail page. I want this as a navigational feature, rather than a item customisation.

More details - I am using "Colour" as an item customisation feature, however this is an endless list with each swatch an individual photo.

For search, I would like a simplified version of the above, to create east navigation. For example, I might have lime, dark green, bottle green, shade 458 etc for products that are green. In the layered navigation I would like a standard green swatch, linked through to all the green items. I would have to manually fix a hidden standardised-colour attribute for this.

Any ideas on how to do what I want or a better solution?